# Heatmap - with diagonally split tiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Could we use R to plot this figure？One grid cell with two values？

Heatmaps showing the Kuiper distance values (upper-left
triangles) and the (1-PSS) values (bottom-right triangles)

[image]

Actually, this figure has two correlations coefficients, the top left triangle is one and the bottom right triangle is another one. Does anyone know how to plot this figure in R?

I have tried to use these packages, but I can't make it.

```
library(corrplot) 
library(ggcorrplot)
library(GGally)
```

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Otherwise this is very close to "*recommend or find a book, tool, software library*", which on SO is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This appears identical to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416978/could-we-use-r-to-plot-this-figure-one-grid-cell-with-two-variables), which was closed for being unclear. Do read through the references r2evans provided above; they should give you some idea for how to improve the question.

Comment: asking the same question again I see what you are doing ;) I think it is clear two values within a cell for the relationship between two variables.

Comment: What does the split in a single square mean?

Answer (score 0):

### Here an example that works well for me.

```
## First of all define your palette colours with:

### I assume that the dimension of PSS_values= Kuiper_distance_values=8,16 

### "ncol1" will be the palette colours for Kuiper distance values (upper-left triangles) while the "ncol2" will for the (1-PSS) values (bottom-right triangles)



color.gradient <- function(x, colors=c(mypal), colsteps=100) {return(colorRampPalette(colors) (colsteps) [ findInterval(x, seq(min(x),max(x), length.out=colsteps)) ] )}


ncol1=matrix(color.gradient(as.vector(Kuiper_distance_values[,rev(1:16)])),nrow=8,ncol=16)

ncol2=matrix(color.gradient(as.vector(PSS_values[,rev(1:16)])),nrow=8,ncol=16)


y=seq(1,16),x=seq(1,8)

par(mfrow=c(1,1))


par(oma=c(15,8,4,2))

plot(1,1,xlim=c(0.75,8.25),ylim=c(0.75,16.25), type="n",bty="n" ,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")



for(i in 1:8){ 
for(j in 1:16){
polygon(x[i]-0.5+c(0,1,1),y[j]-0.5+c(0,0,1),col=ncol1[i,j])

polygon(x[i]-0.5+c(0,1,0),y[j]-0.5+c(0,1,1),col=ncol2[i,j])

}}


Listofclimateindex=c("Annuelmean","DJFmean","JJAmean","etc")
Listofclimatemodels=c("ERA5I","MERRA2","CRCM5-OUR","CRCM5-UQAM","CanRCM4","HIRHAM5","RCA4","RegCM4","WRF","ENSmean")

axis(side=2, at= 1:16,labels=rev(Listofclimatemodels), las=1, cex.axis=2,font=2)

axis(side=3, at= 1:8,labels=Listofclimateindex,las=1, cex.axis=2.5,font=2)


abline(h=seq(from=0.5,to=ncol(PSS_values[,rev(1:16)])+0.5,by=1),lty=1,col="white",lwd=1)

abline(v=seq(from=0.5,to=nrow(PSS_values[,rev(1:16)])+0.5,by=1),lty=1,col="white",lwd=1)
```